# ubuntu 12.10 won't see my external hard drive

Tags: 12.10, drive, detect

So here's the story: I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my acer aspire 7551 last night without a hitch. I have two hard drives from my now out-of-service desktop that was running windows 7 that I'm trying to copy and backup to the laptop so I can then export them to my external HD. This external is detected and everything, but when I put my hard drives from my desktop in the external case to export the files, Ubuntu doesn't see them. I even have a usb 2.0 to sata cable kit, and that doesn't seem to work either. However, I could see the files of one of this Hd when I had Windows 7 running on the laptop...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I posted a question, which wasn't answered. But I've just found some info - its a bug that has been reported - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1048059

This page gives an answer which seems to be working for me.